# iPhone: Find Location Services in Sysdiagnose?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to extract Location Services data from an iPhone running developer mode, and have installed the "Location Services for iOS" Profile that can be found on the [Profiles and Logs page](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?platform=ios). I have also read the [Instructions PDF](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/iOS_Logs/LocationAndMotion.mobileconfig), and done the setup.

I am having a hard time finding the actual logs after exporting the sysdiagnose folder. The folder is quite big and complex.

Can someone please help me, and tell me where I can find it?

Thanks!

I have tried going through all logs and search for relevant information.